# Why can I not use the 'add a reply' button on Google Product Forums?

Tags: button, calendar, product, reply, forums

I am trying to post a reply here:

[Google Calendar notification when event ENDS - Google Product Forums](http://productforums.google.com/d/topic/calendar/dP0f3h5GWtc)

For reference have responded here:

[time management - end-of-event reminder in calendar app - Stack ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676235/end-of-event-reminder-in-calendar-app)

Answer (score 0):

Google help forum says:

- "Topics are automatically locked after a certain period of inactivity"
- "when I look at the locked topic that there is a padlock to the right of the title"

(The lock symbol is on the same line as the "add a reply" but much closer to the thread title than the button.)

Reference:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/SJpl1cRsYPA